# Hystrix netflix issue

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, hystrix

I am using the following properties for my hystrix implementation

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "circuitBreakerFallbackForGet",commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "THREAD"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.timeout.enabled", value = "false"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "10000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout", value = "false"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "fallback.enabled", value = "true"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.enabled", value = "false"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "100"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "10000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage", value = "50"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.forceOpen", value = "false"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "20000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.forceClosed", value = "false") }, commandKey = "getAccountInfo", groupKey = "getAccountInfo", threadPoolKey = "thread-pool-core-service", threadPoolProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "10") })
```

After adding this code my microservices generally fails and its goes to the fallback method that i have added . I understand that only three values make sense in that and they are

1. `metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds` -- this will be the time limit for the hystrix for considering the failure calculation.
2. `circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage` -- this is the percantage of failures that should happen for fallback to come into picture.
3. `circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold` -- this is the number of request volume that should come atleast in the mentioned timeinMilliseconds then only hystrix will come into picture.

Also I'm providing seperate `commandkey` and `groupkey` for every method where i have added hystrix.

Please suggest how to manage so that it works as expected.

Comment: You disabled timeouts and circuitbreaker and then set other related properties. It doesn't make sense... start by removing most of the properties until it works, then start adding them back one-by-one to see which one causes the issue.

Comment: yes that make sense but even if i make then disable it gives an error that fallback is disabled. Also i wanted to understand how i can change the default properties lets suppose the default timeout is 1000 msec but some of my api's take more then that as internally they are calling more then five endpoints and all of then needs to be called asynchronously.

Comment: [Hystrix documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/configuration) shows how to do it via properties. So if for default you configure: `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy` for a specific *HystrixCommandKey* you'll configure `hystrix.command.HystrixCommandKey.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds`